# How to get back from atan2 angle back to Coordinate

Tags: c++, trigonometry, atan2

I calculated the angle of `(-6/35)` by using `atan2(-6/35)`.
The result is `-9.7275785514016047`.

Now to get back I used  the formula from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates)

[image]

```
distance = sqrt(6*6+35*35);
angleRelativeToPatternOrigin = -9.7275785514016047;

double  x1 = distance * cos(angleRelativeToPatternOrigin);
double  y1 = distance * sin(angleRelativeToPatternOrigin);
```

I exptected to get the coordinares `(-6/35)`
But I got (`-33.895012797701419/10.589056022311761`)

So I think this is wrong because `atan2` is defined over **4** quadrants and `sin` and `cos` are only defined over **2**.

Is this correct?
How to do it right?

**Edit:**

Now, first of all I am sorry for describing my question in a bad way.
I actually did the following

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   int x = -6;
   int y = 35;
   double radian = atan2(x,y);  // this was wrong. atan2(y,x) is correct.
   double degree = radian  * (360 / (2 * 3.14159265358979323846));
   double distance = sqrt(6*6+35*35);

   double x1 = distance * cos(degree); // Wrong because I used degree
   double y1 = distance * sin(degree); // instead of radian

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"I calculated the angle of (-6/35) by using `atan2(-6/35)`"_ No you didn't. The function takes two arguments, not one.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit
 I used -6 as param one and 35 as param two

Comment: That is not what your question says.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to both use the atan2 function to get an angle and to then use sin & cos to get back to cartesian co-ordinates, you need to use them slightly differently, as you've already said.

As LightnessRacesInOrbit and user38034 both said, the atan2 function takes 2 parameters. The first is the y, the second is the x.

Consider the following JS snippet:

```
var x = -6.0;
var y = 35.0;

var at = Math.atan2(y, x);
console.log(at);

var dist = (x*x) + (y*y);
dist = Math.sqrt(dist);
console.log(dist);

var x1 = dist * Math.cos(at);
var y1 = dist * Math.sin(at);

console.log( {x:x1, y:y1} );
```

The output from this snippet is:

```
1.740574600763235
35.510561809129406
Object {x: -5.999999999999998, y: 35}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your using `atan2` in the wrong way. The function declaration of `atan2` is:

```
double atan2 (double y, double x);
```

So the angle is:

```
double angle = atan2(35, -6); // 1.74057 radians or 99.72758 degree
```

Comment: Thank you.
I changed it and now I get 99.72758 degree, but the coordinates are still wrong (24.654041707636729|25.557351730531639)

Comment: @R_Valdez How about showing what you are doing so someone can tell you what is wrong in it, instead of hoping they can guess?

Comment: @R_Valdez All trigonometric functions in C++ (and any language I know) use radians, not degrees. `distance*cos(1.74057)` gives `-6` and `distance*sin(1.74057)` gives `35`.

Comment: @R_Valdez Please read any tutorial on how to ask for help. What you posted does not compile, it is missing key parts.

Comment: @MarcGlisse sorry, next time I will provide the main. (no irony)

Comment: @user38034 You were right, I used degrees instead of radians. You can post this an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @R_Valdez there's no reason to wait for the next time. You can and should fix this question.